# Issue with datetime variable in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to declare a date variable in SQL and when I debug it, it hangs on the `SET` part. There is more to the query, but it essentially loops through, adding different inputs until it hits December 31st.

```
DECLARE @ShiftDate AS Datetime
BEGIN
    SET @ShiftDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'
END
DECLARE @ShiftDate AS DATETIME
BEGIN
SET @ShiftDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'
END

DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
BEGIN
SET @EndDate = '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
END


GO
WHILE @ShiftDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [ManufacturingTracking].[dbo].[TenteringCrewShift]
       ([SearchDate]
       ,[Shift])
 VALUES (@ShiftDate, 'B')
 SET @ShiftDate = DATEADD(DATE, 1, @ShiftDate)
 IF @ShiftDate > @EndDate
    BREAK
 ELSE
    CONTINUE
END
```

And if I tell it to continue on it gives the error:

> *Must declare the scalar variable "@ShiftDate".*

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me, is that your *entire* script?

Comment: Why is the set inside a BEGIN END block?

Comment: You get the same error if you use SET without the BEGIN/END? Works here, but maybe some settings/scope issue?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I updated the question with more of my script to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `GO` from your script; the `GO` is essentially starting a new section of processing, and `@ShiftDate` won't be in scope in the next section of your script.

See the [MSDN documentation on `GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) for more information.